# $f$ continuous nowhere implies $f$ not Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

I am trying to prove the statement in the title, without using the theorem which says that the set of discontinuities of a Riemann integrable function must have measure $0$.  I am aware that similar questions have been asked before, but I am asking for a proof-check rather than an answer.

**Attempt:** Consider $f:\;[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ where $f$ is continuous nowhere on $[a,b]$. We want to show $\mathcal{U}_{f,\mathcal{D}}-\mathcal{L}_{f,\mathcal{D}}\geq (b-a)\eta$ for some $\eta>0$, where $\mathcal{U}_{f,\mathcal{D}},\mathcal{L}_{f,\mathcal{D}}$ are the upper & lower Darboux sums for any partition $\mathcal{D}=\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}:\;a=x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n=b$ of $[a,b]$.

To do this, suppose $f$ is bounded $[$if not we are done$]$, it is sufficient $(?)$ to show that: $$\limsup_{x\to w} f>\liminf_{x\to w} f,\quad \forall w\in (a,b)$$
This is immediate since $\limsup_{x\to w}f=\liminf_{x\to w}f\Rightarrow f$ has at worst a removable discontinuity. $$\eta=\inf\Big\{\big(\limsup_{x\to w} f-\liminf_{x\to w}f\big):\;w\in (a,b)\Big\}$$ $$\Rightarrow\quad\mathcal{U}_{f,\mathcal{D}}-\mathcal{L}_{f,\mathcal{D}}\geq \sum_i (x_{i+1}-x_i)\eta=(b-a)\eta$$

---

First, is this anywhere near a correct approach? Second, there is an issue which I cannot seem to correct: the argument allows $\eta =0$. Can something be fixed to rule this out? Thank you for any help.